# Why can't CMOS simply be made of n-type enhancement mode MOSFETs and n-type depletion mode MOSFETs?

Tags: transistors, digital-logic, cmos, logic-gates

According to my textbook, a CMOS must use both PMOS and NMOS transistors because a CMOS needs transistors that follow the positive logic system and transistors that don't follow the positive logic system. n-type enhancement mode MOSFETs do follow the positive logic system and n-type depletion mode MOSFETs don't follow the positive logic system, so why can't only NMOS transistors be used?

The positive logic system defines 0 (off) as low voltage and 1 (on) as high voltage.

Comment: Depletion mode FETs still "follow the positive logic convention" they just have an awkward requirement for negative gate voltages.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can't CMOS simply be made of n-type enhancement mode MOSFETs and n-type depletion mode MOSFETs?](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/204694/why-cant-cmos-simply-be-made-of-n-type-enhancement-mode-mosfets-and-n-type-depl)

Comment: @BrianDrummond: According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depletion_and_enhancement_modes), depletion mode FETs follow negative logic convention. "In a depletion-mode MOSFET, the device is normally ON at zero gate–source voltage."

Comment: That's not what Wikipedia says.  0V is the more positive of the two interesting gate-source voltages.

Comment: @Travis: The point is whether "opened" or "closed" happens above the threshold voltage.  Simply moving the threshold above or below zero doesn't change that.

Comment: For a depletion device, you still increase the gate-source voltage to turn it on, and decrease the gate-source voltage to turn it off. Changing the thresholds does not suddenly *invert* the polarity of the logic.

Comment: Crossposted from http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/222605/2451

Comment: @Qmechanic The migrated cross-post was deleted by the OP.

Answer (score 5):

That's been done already. It's called ["Depletion-load NMOS"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depletion-load_NMOS_logic), as opposed to "CMOS" with the "C" meaning "complementary", i.e. both NMOSFETs and PMOSFETs.

The primary disadvantages of NMOS are(were):

1. Its power dissipation is higher than CMOS since the pullups never turn off (versus PMOSFETs).
2. Drive strength is asymmetrical due to high-side pullups versus low-side switches.

Answer (score 2):

A NMOS is on when the gate-source voltage is higher than the threshold voltage. For a depletion-mode NMOS, this threshold voltage is negative. Thus, if the gate-source voltage is zero, there is already a n-channel and some current may flow from drain to source. If the gate-source voltage is increased, then more current can flow. Thus, a depletion-mode NMOS still follows the positive logic convention.